# Multidimensional arrays in a IDL File?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, corba, idl

I'm being asked for a program that uses Matrix functions (addition, multiplication, scalar multiplication, invertible matrix) that has a size of 6x6 but I'm wondering if multidimensional arrays can be done in CORBA.

For example, this is a part of the "model" in Java:

```
public class Matrix {    
private final float[][] values;        
public Matrix(int rows, int columns) {
    this.values = new float[rows][columns];
}
```

As far as I know, you can create unidimensional arrays in the IDL file using `sequence` but I'd like to know if it's possible to create multidimensional arrays like this one. I'm trying to code the IDL but I can't find out how.

My question is: **How can you send a Matrix object to the server?**

I really appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A [`typedef`](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jenut/ch10_07.htm) is normally used to associate the type with the required array

```
interface ServerInterface {

    typedef float MatrixArray[10][10];
    void sendMatrix(in MatrixArray array);
};
```